# GDAL 3.6.4 not building on Windows Server 2012 R2 machine

Tags: gdal

I am trying to build GDAL 3.6.4 on Windows Server 2012 R2 machine with VS2017 installed. These are the steps I am using:

1. cmake -G "Visual Studio 15 2017"  -DCMAKE_BUILD_T
   YPE=Release -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON -DGDAL_USE_INTERNAL_LIBS=WHEN_NO_EXTERNAL -DG
   EOS_INCLUDE_DIR= -DGEOS_LIBRARY= -DPROJ_INCLUDE_DIR= -DPROJ_
   LIBRARY_RELEASE= -DJSONC_INCLUDE_DIR= -DJSONC_LIBRARY= -DGDAL_USE
   _CURL=OFF -DGDAL_USE_PCRE2=OFF -DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=<openssl 3.0.10 path> ..
2. Cmake —build .
3. Cmake - -build . —target install

Step no 1 & 2 is running fine but while running step 3 I am getting this error and the binaries are not getting installed.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. It's possible that you could have an image which is more difficult to read, but only just barely. Error messages need to be in the body of the Question as text, so they are legible on all devices, and searchable by others with the same problem.

Comment: Sure Vince , will take this tour.